# Send line break to GSP

Tags: grails

I need to send a string to my view that includes line breaks. If my controller says:

```
def answer = "Line 1<br/>Line 2"
render answer
```

It displays two lines of text in the view. But I need it to work with:

```
def answer = "Line 1<br/>Line 2"
[answer: answer]
```

where I have an ${answer} tag in my gsp. When I do the above, I get a single line exactly as it appears in the quotes. How do I get my tag to interpret the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return Line 1 and Line 2 as array

For Example

```
IN Controller
String[] answer = null

answer.add(Line1)
answer.add(Line2)
[answer: answer]

In GSP
${answer.get(1)}<br />${answer.get(2)}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks. I think that is the right approach instead of putting the HTML in the string. I used a g:each tag in the GSP to allow for an arbitrary number of elements in the array.